# c++ API for sql on windows

Tags: c++, sql, windows

i have got one small database on microsoft sql and i wannato acces it using c++ api not the vc++ so can any one suggest me how should i do this...

Comment: What's the C++ API as opposed to the VC++ one? I'm not clear what the distinction is.

Comment: i don't wanna use any of the Microsoft specific components !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at [ADO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681025%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). It's a set of COM classes (so not Visual C++ specific) that can be used from any Windows C++ compiler.

If on the other hand you're after a cross platform approach to accessing databases in C++, you might want to have a look at [SQLAPI++](http://www.sqlapi.com/)

Answer (score 0):

By googling your question, I found this:

http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/2864/

BTW, why not use ADO or something like that?

Comment: i have been there,but thanx for your effort